# Usage of 'into' after 'penetrate'

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

Somehow I have difficulties telling which one is more correct

*They penetrate **into** the building* OR *They penetrate the building*

I've heard it being used both ways and I'd like to hear some thoughts on that.

Thanks.

Comment: You heard them used both ways, because they mean different things. *They penetrate the building* implies that they went through the structure; *They penetrate **into** the building* means that they went through *something* and reached the inside of the building. Both are correct.

Comment: Who or what are "they"? It makes a difference. If the subject is a police squad, for example a [SWAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAT) team, or tremors from an earthquake. (I'm finding it a challenge to think of things which "penetrate into" a building)

Comment: @Mari-LouA That should hardly matter, I suppose.

Comment: @Kris  If the squad is waiting outside the building, I think it does make a slight difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Penetrate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/penetrate?s=t) means to pierce or pass *into* or through. If you are going to use *into* after *penetrate*, it would be redundant.

> The bullet penetrated the wall. The fog lights penetrated the mist.

By substitution, if you used *into* after *penetrate*, it would be:

> The bullet *pierced into* into the wall. The fog lights *passed into* into the mist.

Comment: Your example and usage are different from the OP's.

Answer (score 2):

You heard them used both ways, because they mean different things.

> They penetrate the building

implies that they go through the structure.

> They penetrate **into** the building

means that they go through *something* (the walls?) and reach the inside of the building.

Both are correct.

Comment: Will the invisible pundit please comment?